# Error connect remote MongoDB Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect to the remote atlas bank, however it looks like I'm being redirected to localhost. I configured spring.data.mongodb.uri as usual, that same project was working a few days ago and other projects with the same structure are working normally. With the same connection uri, I can connect via the mongoDB client.
I'm using spring boot 2.6, below is the dependencies used via gradle

````
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit', name: 'htmlunit', version: '2.39.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.17'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-openfeign', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'io.github.openfeign.form', name: 'feign-form', version: '3.8.0'
    compile group: 'io.github.openfeign', name: 'feign-jaxb', version: '10.7.4'
    compile ('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.8.0')
    compile ('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.8.0')
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.3.1'
    compile group: 'com.github.mpkorstanje', name: 'simmetrics-core', version: '4.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-scratchpad', version: '4.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-parsers', version: '1.23'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-core', version: '1.23'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    testCompile group: 'com.google.caliper', name: 'caliper', version: '0.5-rc1'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}```

This log error: "Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017"

I saw some comments telling me to disable @EnableAutoConfiguration (exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class}), however, it didn't work, after all I'm trying to connect to a remote mongo and don't disable it.

It seems to me something related to the configuration of routes / dns something like that, I don't know, I'm confused about that. Would any good soul know how to help me?
````

Comment: Unrelated: don't forget to update pdfbox, poi and tika.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Auto-Configuration "ON" it uses default values which points to localhost:27017. That's why you saw comments telling to exclude MongoAutoConfiguration and MongoDataAutoConfiguration in SpringBootApplication/EnableAutoConfiguration annotations.

I would suggest you configure mongodb programmatically (instead of auto) and override these props.

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongoserver.example.com
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
spring.data.mongodb.username=user
spring.data.mongodb.password=secret
```

Comment: but my setup worked previously and on other projects it works. Could it be something related to the environment? I didn't understand why it just stopped working.

Comment: it might be possible that the. spring boot version of this project is upgraded